# cache images for offline usage Android

Tags: android, caching, universal-image-loader, picasso

Currently I'm using Picasso Library to download and cache images of my list-view but it only keeps cache for sometime. I also tried Universal Image Loader too, but the same problem persists, images only available for sometime. Can anybody please tell me how whatsApp, Gmail, Google Inbox etc. Cache images for offline usage. Whether they are using some libraries or they custom code to cache/save images...Please guide!